# Cocos2d - CCSprite image texture gets blurred

Tags: iphone, image, cocos2d-iphone, ccsprite

i am using the latest  cocos2d to create a game project,i have added the images having respective retina and normal images.But when ever i add a ccsprite with its initialize method ,initWithFileName:(NSString*)fileName ,the image texture gets blurred while running ,in retina and non retina devices

Answer (score 1):

For all texture OR only for some texture? If it is for all texture then change pixelFormat.

In AppController, set backbuffer pixelFormat to kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8.

```
CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try this on your sprite:

```
[myccsprite setAliasTexParameters];
```

It will tell the sprite not to anti-alias.

Comment: In AppController,i set backbuffer pixelFormat to kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8.This really worked.

Answer (score -3):

In AppController,i set backbuffer pixelFormat to kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8.This really worked

CCGLView *glView = [CCGLView viewWithFrame:[window_ bounds]
                                   pixelFormat:kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8    //kEAGLColorFormatRGBA8
                                   depthFormat:0    //GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT24_OES
                            preserveBackbuffer:NO
                                    sharegroup:nil
                                 multiSampling:NO
                               numberOfSamples:0];

Comment: @nassif: the way it works is - you accept and upvote his answer, not copy it and add it as your own :)